# Can't connect to Wifi after switching to Google WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless

So recently I've bought a Google Wifi router to get dual band access easily in my house.
Thing is, ever since I've made the shift, my laptop (a Thinkpad X230i) that is running Ubuntu 19.04 refuses to connect to my WiFi network. It sees the network, asks for the password, but never connects. I've tried almost all Linux distributions, but none of them seem to connect to the network. Windows works fine, however.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Help is appreciated.
Here is the network card info:

```
    00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e

    03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Edit: Sorry for the late update. I did as cmak.fr asked me to do and here is the result from the command I ran. I'll be just posting it directly, I don't know how to format correctly, sorry.

The "Received SIGWINCH" line keeps repeating when I try to connect after running the command. Thanks for the help.

```
grep: NetworkManager: No such file or directory
No configuration file specified.
dbus-daemon [--version] [--session] [--system] [--config-file=FILE] [--print-address[=DESCRIPTOR]] [--print-pid[=DESCRIPTOR]] [--introspect] [--address=ADDRESS] [--nopidfile] [--nosyslog] [--syslog] [--syslog-only] [--nofork] [--fork] [--systemd-activation]
Startup finished in 81ms.
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
kernel: command not found


pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.

pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.

pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.

pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.

pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.

pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.

pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.

pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.

pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.

pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.

pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.

pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

pulseaudio.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.

Received SIGWINCH.

Received SIGWINCH.

Received SIGWINCH.

Received SIGWINCH.
```

Comment: For a debug work, you should watch logs. Run this `tail -f -n100 /var/log/syslog | grep -E --line-buffered 'NetworkManager|wpa_supplicant|kernel|dhclient|dbus-daemon|systemd'` then hit RETURN key several times to mark the start of watching, then try to connect to WiFi. Then edit your post with a https://paste.ubuntu.com/ post of your logs. Thank you